# How do I fix this script for Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

The script is supposed to allow my first person controller/player go up to an object, press the E key and then pickup and carry the object around. There are errors in the script and I don't understand how to program yet. I've also attached the screenshot of the errors in the code for reference.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PickupObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject mainCamera;
    bool carrying;
    GameObject carriedObject;
    public float distance;
    public float smooth;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        mainCamera = GameObject.FindWithTag("MainCamera");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (carrying)
        {
            carry(carriedObject);
            checkDrop();
        }
        else
        {
            pickup();
        }
    }

    void carry(GameObject o)
    {
        o.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
        o.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (mainCamera.transform.position + mainCamera.transform.forward * distance, Time.deltaTime * smooth);
    }

    void pickup() 
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown KeyCode.E;))
        {
            int x = Screen.width / 2;
            int y = Screen.height / 2;
        }

        Ray ray = mainCamera.GetComponent<Camera>().ScreentPointToRay(new Vector3(x, y));
        RaycastHit hit;
        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            Pickupable p = hit.collider.GetComponent<Pickupable>();
            if(p != null)
            {
                carrying = true;
                carriedObject = p.gameObject;
                p.gameObject.rigidbody.isKinematic = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

void checkDrop()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    {
        dropObject();
    }
    void dropObject()
    {
        carrying = false;
        carriedObject = null;
        carriedObject.gameObject.rigidbody.isKinematic = false;
    }
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: even if you dont entirely understand, fix the first problem, check it, see what it says now.. etc..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try using Raycasts to pickup items. Create a "Pick Up" tag, add that tag to all pickup-able items, shoot a Raycast from the camera in the direction of the camera if the player presses 'E', check if the hit has the tag, then pick it up. Search up "Raycast tutorial" and you will find many results.

Comment: I figured it out, added a new script, there are no errors in the code now but the objects that I am trying to pickup are floating in the air and don't drop when I let go of them. I have a rigid body on there with both gravity and kinematic, tried disabling kinematic and it wont pick up but will fall to the ground. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Within `pickup` you define `int x` and `int y` inside of an `if` block.

The second issue is that within (or after) the `pickup` method you have one closing `}` to much.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown KeyCode.E;))
{
    int x = Screen.width / 2;
    int y = Screen.height / 2;
} // <-- SEEMS THAT THIS HERE IS YOUR PROBLEM !
```

So you basically end your class before the method `checkDrop`. The rest are just follow up errors: The `x` and `y` will be known only within this code block and when you later try to use them in

```
Ray ray = mainCamera.GetComponent<Camera>().ScreentPointToRay(new Vector3(x, y));
```

they do not exist.

Also as said you and the class so the method `checkDrop` is not known in `Update`. And then you get some additional errors anyway since it is not allowed to define a method outside of a type.

---

Note that I formatted your code so it should be quite clear now. You probably rather wanted it do to be

```
void pickup() 
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown KeyCode.E;))
    {
        int x = Screen.width / 2;
        int y = Screen.height / 2;
    
        Ray ray = mainCamera.GetComponent<Camera>().ScreentPointToRay(new Vector3(x, y));
        RaycastHit hit;
        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            Pickupable p = hit.collider.GetComponent<Pickupable>();
            if(p != null)
            {
                carrying = true;
                carriedObject = p.gameObject;
                p.gameObject.rigidbody.isKinematic = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```